# How to derive conditional destribution of MVN variable

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, multivariate-normal-distribution, determinant

I am working with following model specifications (Regression_ Modelle, Methoden und Anwendungen-Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg (2009), p. 147):

$$Y \sim MVN(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$$
$$\beta|\sigma^2 \sim MVN(m, \sigma^2M)$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim IG(a_0, b_0)$$

The author derives the joint prior as follows:
[image]

My question is how does the author get the $(\sigma^2)^{\frac{p}{2}}$. I got the $p(\beta|\sigma^2)$ like:
$$p(\beta|\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{p}{2}}det(\sigma^2 M)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \cdot exp(-\frac{1}{2} (\beta-m)^{T}(\sigma^2 M)^{-1}(\beta-m))$$
How is the $det(\sigma^2 M)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ handled correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Immediate_consequences

Comment: Thank you man :)